# Async Redux Action: add auth token to fetch() request

Tags: javascript, firebase, authentication, asynchronous, redux

I currently have an async redux action (w/ Middleware) which fetches data from my backend.  I am adding Firebase authentication, and want to include the auth token to this request.  The auth token is fetched asynchronously using the function `getAuthToken()` below.  The below code doesn't work, complaining

> Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined

This simple task, chaining the output of one async to another, but I'm new to JS.  How can I accomplish this?

```
// I'm sure returning from an async function like this is wrong.
function getAuthToken() {
  firebase
    .auth()
    .currentUser.getIdToken(/* forceRefresh */ true)
    .then(idToken => {
      return idToken;
    });
}

// Async redux action.
export function getData(userId) {
  return dispatch => {
    return fetch(`${BASE_URL}/data/${userId}`, {
      headers: { Authorization: getAuthToken().resolve() } // Can I even resolve like this?
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => dispatch(returnSurveys(json)));
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short-term solution: first await for token then send your request.

```
function getAuthToken() {
  return firebase
    .auth()
    .currentUser.getIdToken(/* forceRefresh */ true)
    .then(idToken => {
      return idToken;
    });
}

export function getData(userId) {
  return dispatch => {
    return getAuthToken().then(token => 
      fetch(`${BASE_URL}/data/${userId}`, {
        headers: { Authorization: token } // Can I even resolve like this?
      })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => dispatch(returnSurveys(json))));
  };
}
```

Downside: calling `getAuthToken` each time you want to ask backend for something is definitely bad practice.

So you better put token into Redux as well as other data is.

And then you may either pass token from outside:

```
export function getData(userId, token) { ....
```

Or, probably better, ask store for token right in your thunk(second parameter `getState` is passed by `redux-thunk`):

```
export function getData(userId) {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    return fetch(`${BASE_URL}/data/${userId}`, {
      headers: { Authorization: getState().path.to.token.in.your.store } 
    })
```

For some period it assumed to be rather bad approach, that's why it's not widely known. But there are different [points of view](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/01/idiomatic-redux-thoughts-on-thunks-sagas-abstraction-and-reusability/) and to me your case suiting that very well.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer! The quick fix worked, but in the long term I will definitely store the token in redux via thunk.